# Click on webpage button

Tags: r, web, click

I would like to know how to click on the "EXPORT GRID" icon to download an xlsx. Note that the URL can be changed according to the background code.

Link: https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=15578550000160

Rvest and Rselenium didn't work.

When running the suggested code:

Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
Detail: A new session could not be created.
Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.

> remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate(url)
Error in checkError(res) :
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: When you say "Rvest and Rselenium didn't work" what does that mean exactly? What did you try? What problems did you have?

Comment: Please do not provide images of code. Rather, copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. A more detailed description of what you've tried and what errors your seen would help us give a better answer :)

```
# Load library ---------------------------------------------------------------
library(RSelenium)

# Define url--------------------------------------------------------------
url <- "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=15578550000160"

# set up RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)

# Click on the button -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$findElements("id", "btnExport")[[1]]$clickElement()
```

Comment: Selenium server I had tried exactly the same code, however, the first error it gives is this:


Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
  Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
   Detail: A new session could not be created.
  Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.

Comment: Edit your question to include that. It'd also be helpful to know what you see when you run the errorDetails method and what's in the server log. You should also say what operating system and browser you tried to use.

Comment: Also include which command you ran right before seeing the error

Comment: This "Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE"